# Plotting a curve from a text document located in E drive using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a text document " Data n(r) vs r" in E drive in which there are two columns. I want to plot the values in the first column vs the second column using python. I am using the below code to do this. But I get an error ' No such file or directory Data n(r) vs r' . Can somebody please help me in fixing the error The code is as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X, Y = [], []
for line in open('Data n(r) vs r.txt', 'r'):
    values = [float(s) for s in line.split()]
    X.append(values[0])
    Y.append(values[1])
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.grid(True)

Output
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Data n(r) vs r.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then reference to the full path:

```
for line in open(r'E:\Data n(r) vs r.txt', 'r'):
```

Fix other error with

```
values = [float(s) for s in line.strip().split()]
```

Comment: Yes now the file has opened. But again a different error is coming.X, Y = [], []
     90 for line in open(r'F:\MTP Files\Abu Orabi\Data n(r) vs r .txt', 'r'):
---> 91     values = [float(s) for s in line.split()]
     92     X.append(values[0])
     93     Y.append(values[1])

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x'

Comment: Yes , resolved now. Thanks very much for your efforts.